# Assign names to Weblogic's 10.3.5 specific Work Manager

Tags: weblogic-10.x, workmanagers

There is any way to assign names to specific Weblogic Work Manager threads?

**for example:**
I defined a work manager called: TestWorkManager, each time that this work manager executes some task the following line will be printed to the log file.

> {[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'}

in this way i can't actually know which work manager executes the task, so i want to assignnames to his threads.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that **threads are not executed by WorkManager** as they are more like **Policy/Strategy** which are used to manage them (e.g : Thread Scheduling). That is WorkManager is not Thread Pool nor Thread Queue.

Thus Weblogic will log WorkManager's name for things that are **directly related to its role** and not for all executions (e.g : Stuck thread, Min/Max constraints, etc...)

AdminServer console displays threads' WorkManager's name in **Server:Monitoring:Thread**

The JVM flag **-Dweblogic.StuckThreadHandling=true** can be used to append WorkManager's name in log files when a stuck thread is reported.

You can enable specific debug info/key using AdminServer console in **Server:Debug** e.g **weblogic.work.[*]**

*I don't have yet enough experience about WLS but if what you described is possible then I would be pleased to get the answer as **I also need it that way***